# Where the parameters of variadic functions in C are stored?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

When we have variadic functions in C we only know the amount of memory for storing them in execution time. So, I think it is necessary some kind of dynamic memory allocation for allocating them. I was wondering if this data is stored in the stack or in the heap.

Comment: Re “When we have variadic functions in C we only know the amount of memory for storing them in execution time”: This is not correct. The called function has no advance information on the arguments it is passed, and, in the perspective of compiling the called function by itself, there is no information available on what arguments are passed. However, where the function is called, all of the arguments and their types are visible and known.

Variadic arguments are commonly passed in processor registers and on the stack. The details depend on the target platform.

Comment: The C11 standard contains zero mentions of the word "stack". It's uh... "objects with automatic storage duration". The precise details are up to the implementation.

Comment: @teapot418 This becomes important when implementing some code that is supposed to interop with assembly or other languages.

Comment: This is typically defined in an ABI document for an architecture. For C as a whole, see above. If you want details, pick a specific architecture like [x64 Linux](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf).

Comment: In the context of C, people who use the term "heap" (not itself a C term) ordinarily mean memory from which dynamic memory allocation requests are served.  Thus, if you're supposing that dynamic allocation is involved then I don't understand where the stack *vs*. heap question is coming from: if it's allocated dynamically then that implies heap.

Comment: However, inasmuch as the storage for a variadic function's variable arguments is managed by the C implementation, not explicitly by the program, we already know that that storage is *not* dynamically allocated, at least as far as C is concerned. So *not* heap.

Comment: If you're asking about how this is done on a particular implementation, or on a "typical" implementation, you should probably clarify that.  By default, people often assume that questions tagged [tag:c] are about the language itself as abstractly defined by the ISO standard, which of course does not have any concept of things like "stack".  (Question for others: is there a better tag for questions about *implementing* C? I guess there is [tag:compiler-construction] but not sure if that really fits either.)

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation isn't needed. Even though the function can receive an arbitrary number of arguments, the *caller* knows the number of arguments statically. It's similar to the way a function can receive an array argument of any size,  but the declaration of the array in the caller will have a known size.

Comment: Notice that C doesn't provide any mechanism for creating variadic argument lists dynamically.